# ERROR requesting with Entrez.efetch() - Biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I would like to know if someone can tell me what's wrong with my code. Thanks by your time

I'm trying to parse genomes of pseudomonas to obtain and extract the 16s RNA sequence gene from each genome from the NCBI. So I searched different genomes and I took the GenBank Assembly and RefSeq Assembly (e.g *P.aestus*, **GenBank Assembly:** GCA_000474765.1,  **RefSeq Assembly:** GCF_000474765.1 ) and use it to search the genome via Entrez in biopython, using the following code:

```
handle= Entrez.esearch(db="genome", 
              term="GCA_000474765.1 [ASAC]")
records= (Entrez.read(handle)["IdList"])
records
```

**Output:**

```
['87847']
```

Then I use **esummary** to obtain the data:

```
handle= Entrez.esummary(db="genome", id=records[0], report= "full")
record= Entrez.read(handle)
record
```

Output

```
[{'Item': [], 'Id': '87847', 'Organism_Name': 'Pseudomonas aestus', 'Organism_Kingdom': 'Bacteria', 'DefLine': '', 'ProjectID': '0', 'Number_of_Chromosomes': '0', 'Number_of_Plasmids': '0', 'Number_of_Organelles': '0', 'Assembly_Name': 'CMAA1215_1.0', 'Assembly_Accession': 'GCA_000474765.1', 'AssemblyID': '67571', 'Create_Date': '2013/10/18 00:00', 'Options': ''}]
```

It seems Ok, so I tried **efetch** to obtain the genome

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id="87847", rettype="gb", retmode="text")
```

But I get this error:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I have tried changing the db (nucleotide, nnucore, genome), the id ("67571","CMAA1215_1.0", "GCA_000474765.1") and I got the same error. Anyone one could tell me what can I do to obtain the sequence genome?

Thanks again by your time!!

Comment: Where did you get the value of `id="87847"`?  How do you know that's a valid id to request?

Comment: I got this from the **Entrez.esearch**, on the first step (`records["IdList"]`)

Comment: You can't mix Unique Identifiers (UID). Refer to this table: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25497/table/chapter2.T._entrez_unique_identifiers_ui/?report=objectonly

Comment: You are attempting to use a "Genome ID" on a database that recognizes "GI number". You'll have to adjust your esearch to get the correct ID or find a way to get the sequence from the genome database (not sure if database has this info).